# How to analyse a stored procedure to identify if rows are returned

Tags: c#, t-sql, antlr4

Given a storedprocedure definition I can easily identify if `SELECT` statements are present.  Some `selects`, however, do not result in rows returned.

I am using the ANTLR4 grammar files provided [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/tsql/TSqlParser.g4) and [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/tsql/TSqlLexer.g4) and [CaseChangingCharstream.cs](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/resources/CaseChangingCharStream.cs). (I found I needed to change lines 71 & 73 `LA` to `La`)

So far I have been unable to identify the correct listener overrides I should be using for my use-case (`EnterSelect_that_returns_rows()` would have been too easy :))

The following tests illustrate the problem.

```
        private TSqlParser GetParser(string sql)
    {
        AntlrInputStream input = new AntlrInputStream(sql);

        CaseChangingCharStream upperCase = new CaseChangingCharStream(input, true);

        TSqlLexer lexer = new TSqlLexer(upperCase);

        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        return new TSqlParser(tokens);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestProcedureWithSelect()
    {
        TSqlParser parser = GetParser("CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc BEGIN print 'Testing'; SELECT 'Hello World'; END;");

        TestListener listener = new TestListener();

        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();

        bool built = parser.BuildParseTree;

        walker.Walk(listener, parser.tsql_file());

        Assert.IsTrue(listener.ReturnsRows); // Passes but 'so what'
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestProcedureWithSelectParam()
    {
        TSqlParser parser = GetParser("CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc BEGIN DECLARE @var nvarchar(256); print 'Testing'; SELECT @var = 'Hello World'; END;");

        TestListener listener = new TestListener();

        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();

        bool built = parser.BuildParseTree;

        walker.Walk(listener, parser.tsql_file());

        Assert.IsFalse(listener.ReturnsRows); // Pass, but probably a kludge 
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestInsertInto()
    {
        TSqlParser parser = GetParser("CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc BEGIN DECLARE @var nvarchar(256); print 'Testing'; INSERT INTO TABLE (FIELD) SELECT 'Hello World'; END;");

        TestListener listener = new TestListener();

        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();

        bool built = parser.BuildParseTree;

        walker.Walk(listener, parser.tsql_file());

        Assert.IsFalse(listener.ReturnsRows); //Fails (I have no solution for this)
    }
}
```

What I have so far looks like this

```
using Antlr4.Runtime.Misc;
using ANTLRTSqlParser.Grammar; 

namespace ParserTests
{
    public class TestListener : TSqlParserBaseListener
    {
        public bool ReturnsRows = false;

        public override void EnterSelect_list([NotNull] TSqlParser.Select_listContext context)
        {
            var elements = context.select_list_elem();

            if(!elements[0].GetText().Contains("=")) 
                ReturnsRows = true;
        }
    }   
}
```

---

I have now added the following to my listener.  I wonder if anyone can comment on the wisdom of using flags in this way

```
private bool inDML = false;
public override void EnterDml_clause([NotNull] TSqlParser.Dml_clauseContext context)
{
    inDML = true;
}

public override void ExitDml_clause([NotNull] TSqlParser.Dml_clauseContext context)
{
    inDML = false;
}

public override void EnterSelect_statement([NotNull] TSqlParser.Select_statementContext context)
{
    ReturnsRows = !inDML;
}
```

---

I have decided to go with this

```
private Stack<bool> nonRowReturningStatements = new Stack<bool>();

public override void EnterDml_clause([NotNull] TSqlParser.Dml_clauseContext context) { nonRowReturningStatements.Push(true); }

public override void ExitDml_clause([NotNull] TSqlParser.Dml_clauseContext context) { nonRowReturningStatements.Pop(); }

public override void EnterDeclare_statement([NotNull] TSqlParser.Declare_statementContext context)  { nonRowReturningStatements.Push(true); }

public override void ExitDeclare_statement([NotNull] TSqlParser.Declare_statementContext context) { nonRowReturningStatements.Pop(); }

public override void EnterDeclare_cursor([NotNull] TSqlParser.Declare_cursorContext context) { nonRowReturningStatements.Push(true); }

public override void ExitDeclare_cursor([NotNull] TSqlParser.Declare_cursorContext context) { nonRowReturningStatements.Pop(); }

public override void EnterSet_statement([NotNull] TSqlParser.Set_statementContext context) { nonRowReturningStatements.Push(true); }

public override void ExitSet_statement([NotNull] TSqlParser.Set_statementContext context) { nonRowReturningStatements.Pop(); }

public override void EnterSelect_statement([NotNull] TSqlParser.Select_statementContext context)
{
    if (!FuncProc.ReturnsRows && nonRowReturningStatements.Count == 0)
    {
        FuncProc.ReturnsRows = !context.query_expression()
                                       .query_specification()
                                       .select_list()
                                       .select_list_elem()[0]
                                       .GetText()
                                       .Contains("=");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible to write a test that ascertains a procedure will *never* return a result set, but it is very hard to make it complete (i.e. the test never says "it might" when it won't). For starters, the procedure could call out to other procedures (so you'd have to analyze those) and might build statements dynamically and `EXEC` them. Aside from these technicalities, you also have to check for `OUTPUT` clauses in statements other than `SELECT`. There are probably not many scenarios where a static test like this is superior to using `sp_describe_first_result_set`.

Comment: @Jeroen - you are quite right

Comment: The test is merely to illustrate some of the use-cases for SO readers.  I also have the headache of a number of sps that return resultsets from dynamic sql.  I am handling these by means of a comment in the sp `-- MYHINT ReturnsRows`.

Comment: Also, I am parsing sps in a visual studio project so the sp in question may not yet have been deployed to a database. For my purposes I think 'might' is equivalent to 'will'.

Comment: Yes, but automatic deployment to a DB for purposes of testing is cheap and easy, with [LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb) and [database projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/project-oriented-offline-database-development). This also allows for actual logic tests. I'm not saying static analysis is useless, of course (DB projects themselves use static analysis, for starters), but for sprocs it tends to be much more complicated/costly than just running the code.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - you have given me an idea.  I already have code that walks the EXEC tree of a deployed database (I used this for calculating permissions).  I could use that to embed my MYHINT kludge .... hmmmm

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I am not testing, I am building c# code from `sqlproj`s.   I posted a couple of unit tests in case anyone want quickly to spin up some code to analyse this particular question.

Comment: Yes, none of what I've said is an answer, hence why it's all comments. :-) You may also want to consider the DacFX library, including its `TSqlParser` and `TSqlModel` classes, as those are the things used to build database code from database projects (and vice versa). I don't know if those are easier/more convenient in your scenario than ANTLR, as I have no experience parsing T-SQL with ANTLR, but I would in any case expect that parser to be more complete, and `TSqlModel` can also be used to retrieve things like types.

Comment: The grammar files I am using have come on by leaps and bounds recently, thanks to @IvanKochurkin and his team and I think they are at least complete enough for my purposes.  Plus I have investment now in ANTLR with other successful projects.

Comment: I may be missing the point here, but do SProcs not declare a signature as part of their definition that informs what the inputs and outputs are?  If not, then I withdraw the comment.  If so, I would be investigating the signature, not the body of the SProc.

Comment: @v0rl0n - that is partially true.  Input and output parameters are declared first, in the signature. Some procs will perform only updates, some will return resultsets. What I need to be able to do is detect if the body of a proc will yield a resultset.